# Can I use an image from the system on a button or do I have to draw my own?

Tags: android

I have a delete button which I'd like to have as a wastepaper basket icon. Similar to the one at the bottom of the home screen which appears when you hold down a shortcut.

Is it possible to re-use Android system Icons, or do I have to draw my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Check out this page: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ for a list of all the usable icons. There is a usage example at the top, but if you are doing this in a menu.xml file, use some code that looks like this

```
<item android:id="@+id/end"
    android:title="@string/end_label"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/end_shortcut"
    android:icon = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
```

Comment: Cheers. Actually looks like there's nothing suitable there (the wastebasket was too big and the X was too red) so I'll have to draw my own anyway, or just use text :-(

Comment: Le Sigh. The website you linked seems to be 404 as of March, 2016. But see http://androiddrawables.com/ instead.

Answer (score 5):

FrinkTheBrave,

You can access many of the system drawables through `android.R.drawable.<drawable here>` programmatically or `android:icon=@android:drawable/<drawable here>` in XML. [This site](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) contains a full list of drawables, but some of them are private and therefor unusable by the user.  If you are using Eclipse, intellisense should pull up a list of available drawables when you type `android.R.drawable`.